# All Required Permissions to Create ModifyAllData PermissionSet

Tags: unit-test, permission-sets

I have a class where I check if the User has ModifyAllData permission:

```
SELECT PermissionSet.PermissionsModifyAllData
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
      AND PermissionSet.PermissionsModifyAllData = TRUE
LIMIT 1
```

In my unit test I want to create PermissionSet with PermissionsModifyAllData = true but I have the following kind of errors when I deploy the code:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Permission ViewAllData depends on permission(s): ViewAllForecasts

which varies from sandbox to sandbox (or scratch), depending on which features are enabled in the org.

How I can get all the dependent permission for ViewAllData (ModifyAllData)?

One way I found is by using DescribeSObjectResult and enabling all Permissions, but is there any better solution?

```
PermissionSet modifyAllData = new PermissionSet(
    Label = 'Test_Modify_All_Permission_Set',
    Name = 'Test_Modify_All_Permission_Set',
    PermissionsModifyAllData = true,
    PermissionsViewAllData = true
);

DescribeSobjectResult permissionSetDescribe = Schema.PermissionSet.SObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, SObjectField> fieldMap = permissionSetDescribe.fields.getMap();

for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()) {
    if (!fieldName.startsWithIgnoreCase('Permissions')) {
        continue;
    }
    DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
    if (fieldDescribe.isCreateable() && fieldDescribe.isUpdateable()) {
        modifyAllData.put(fieldDescribe.getName(), true);
    }
}

insert modifyAllData;
```

The above solution gives me the following errors:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The user license doesn't allow the
>   permission: OptOutGeoLocationTracking: []

which means that not all available permissions could be enables because of the user's licence.

Comment: why not find an active user that is profile = System Administrator as that profile as Modify All Data configured by default and can't be changed?

Answer (score 0):

From this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321298&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1):

> - Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All on all standard and custom objects
> - Convert Leads
> - Create and Customize Reports
> - Edit Events
> - Edit Personal Quota
> - Edit Tasks
> - Import Leads
> - Import Solutions
> - Manage Categories
> - Manage Dashboards
> - Manage Public Documents
> - Manage Public List Views
> - Manage Public Reports
> - Manage Public Templates
> - Override Forecasts
> - Run Reports
> - Transfer Leads
> - Transfer Record
> - Use Team Reassignment Wizards
> - View All Data
> - View All Forecasts
> - View Setup and Configuration

Comment: If I list all those permissions, then I get errors like 
`Field does not exist: PermissionsViewDataLeakageEvents on PermissionSet`
depending on the features enabled in the org. I need somehow dynamically get all dependent permissions that available in the org.